# How to optimize CTE query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following query (for the sake of this topic it was simplified as below):

```
   WITH CTE
   (
         Columns,
         DeliverDate,
         LastReplayDate
   )
   AS
   (
         SELECT IIF(LastReplayDate IS NULL, IIF(LastReplayDate>= DeliverDate, LastReplayDate,DeliverDate),LastReplayDate) AS SortDateColumn,R.* FROM
                (

                       SELECT 
                       Columns,
                       DeliverDate,
                       LastReplayDate
                       FROM MY_TABLE

                       WHERE
                              CONDITIONS
                              AND ( FIRST_HEAVY_FUNCTION)
                              AND ( SECOND_HEAVY_FUNCTION)
                ) R

                ORDER BY SortDateColumn DESC
                       OFFSET (@CurrentPageIndex - 1) * @PageSize ROWS
                FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
   )
   SELECT CTE. *
   FROM CTE
   OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

As you see I use CTE query from sorted data from other query. Last one include pagging each 10 rows.

The most problematic for me here is part:

```
                   WHERE
                          CONDITIONS
                          AND ( FIRST_HEAVY_FUNCTION)
                          AND ( SECOND_HEAVY_FUNCTION)
```

Because of those conditions return time sometimes reach up to 4 minutes or so. Without it's fairly quick (8-20 sec).
Of course indexes were made and improved a query from 15 minutes. But this is still to slow.

I was wondering is it possible to move problematic conditions outside CTE and at the same time still get all 10 rows from paging? In case where rows count < 10 do another loop to collect missing rows to achieve exactly 10 rows as final result.
Is it possible? Or how to optimize a such query?

Comment: Performance related questions need a execution plan using Paste The Plan... and you can't simplify a query you need performance help with because thats not how performance works. SQL purely describes the results you want to achieve, it doesn't tell the engine how to obtain them, it works that out for itself. So while there are some rules of thumb, to properly performance tune a query requires full details of tables, indexes, execution plan etc.

Comment: One of those rules of thumb however is never to put a function in a `WHERE` clause because typically that requires a full table scan. Ideally you want your `WHERE` clause to involve columns that are indexed.

Comment: Implementing both unsargable functions and [paging](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page) like this is going to have very poor performance and *option recompile* is unlikely to help as probably a full scan is always required regardless

Comment: Thanks Dale. You are right. I checked carefully execution plan, and my current result duration time is  based on it. The entire query is really long (around 700 lines including all calculations going on inside and outside). That's why pasting exectution plan would be a problematic, and don't believe anybody would like deep into that ;) That's why I thought it's easier to show simple version of it.  And you are also right about WHERE and full indexed column scan -that's the main problem here, because for result I have to add some extra columns which are based on the same table a couple of times

Comment: Stu - option recompile indeed helps a lot here! This is procedure which comes with 16 parameters.  Depend on user preference some of them can be null. Under that condition recompile does it job fluently.

Comment: Ok if this is a much simplified version then obviously it depends; you only have the page offset parameter in your example.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was wondering whether moving those 2 havy conditions outside is doable? In that case I don't need full table/column scan - just only for returned rows. In my case it would solve the performance issue I guess.

Comment: But we don't have enough information to comment on your last comment. All I can suggest is that you might have a more concrete `WHERE` clause doesn't involve a function, which you can use to pre-filter the results before you apply your functions to them. Otherwise though, there is just not enough details for us to assist.

Comment: Guys the orginal query here for me it's not a case. I would just like to know how to loop those conditions outside a CTE, and go back another loop in case when returned rows count is less than 10. Please focus on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a long time of testing, eventually rewriting a whole query + simplification +cutting part of functionality was the only way.

Thanks to all who tried help with that topic!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions:

1. can you rewrite the functions as inline table valued function? That can allevate the pressure
2. Does the CONDITIONS remove enough rows already? So that the HEAVY_FUNCTIONs are just the cherry on top. In that case you might be able to fake a push down (but i wouldn't guarantee it's always working):

```
select *
from (
    select *
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE
   CONDITIONS
    ) x
cross apply (
    select 1 AS test
    where dbo.FN_SLOW_FUNCTION(x.param1, x.param2) = 1
    ) filter1
cross apply (
    select 1 AS test
    where dbo.FN_ANOTHER_SLOW_FUNCTION(x.param3, x.param4) = 1
    ) filter2
ORDER BY SomeDate OFFSET ...
```

There's a OPTION hint called FORCE ORDER which might guarantee that SQL isn't rearranged too much

3. Are your indexes good?

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! It looks very prommising! Definitelly I'm going to check it in my case. Replaying yours questions: 1) Yeap, it's doable 2) will find out once changes appied 3) yes, I have got 1 clustered index for each main table + a few nonclustered + tables are partitioned well. So I'm sure about indexes. Options with FORDE ORDER and CROSS APPLY might be my sollutions. Let you know after some additional tests. Thank you!

Comment: Ok so turns out that my query is simply to heavy because of numbers of reasons. And the only way is to rewrite it cutting part of functionality. Any way thak you so much for help!